# Enable BRIDGE network for Virt Manager in Ubuntu 21.04 with a Wireless Network only

Tags: networking, 21.04, network-bridge, virt-manager

I've been using Boxes without any problem, the only missing functionality is to access the network outside the guest environment (Boxes Sandbox), from/to another computer in the same LAN.

Because Boxes by design (Sandbox) cannot do it, I installed Virt Manager, nonetheless to enable bridge network in the Guest, I have to enable a bridge in the host first, I followed the instructions with Network Manager, but those are only for an Ethernet network, I haven't found any for A Wireless network.

Is it possible to enable a bridge with a Wireless network in the Host, to use it in the Virt Manager's Guest?